# Error con WebdriverManager y última versión de Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome, chromedriver

Estoy intentando lanzar un test básico de abrir el navegador Chrome con Selenium y Python.
Tengo instalado selenium, webdriver manager, pyhton, etc.

Si lo lanzo con Firefox me abre el navegador de Firefox sin problema:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

formulario_url = "https://www.google.es/"
driver.get(formulario_url)
```

Sin embargo, en Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

formulario_url = "https://www.google.es/"
driver.get(formulario_url)
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\.......\formulario_chrome.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url
    driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Tengo instalada la última versión de Chrome:
*Chrome está actualizado
Versión 120.0.6099.130 (Build oficial) (64 bits)*

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda :)